# Symfony 3.4 form dropdown required but empty to start

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have created a form which populates a dropdown field with objects.

I would like the dropdown field to be required **BUT** also empty (or showing a placeholder) when users first get to the page (so as to not be able to submit the form without actively choosing an option - this is an e-learning context).

Anyone encountered this issue before?

This is my form file :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\QuestionnaireResponses;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class AuditResponseType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('responses', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => AuditOptionType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
            ],
            'label' => false,
        ])
        ;
    }
    
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => QuestionnaireResponses::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
        ));
    } 
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_audit_response';
    }
}
```

And here is my html/twig :

```
                {{ form_start(form) }}
                    <table class="ui compact small celled definition table">
                        <thead class="full-width">
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                {% for context in questionnaire.contexts %}
                                    <th>{{ context.label|raw }}</th>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for question in questionnaire.questions %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="collapsing">
                                        {{ question.title|raw }}
                                    </td>
                                    {% for context in questionnaire.contexts %}
                                        {% set response = form.responses|filter(r => r.vars.data.context == context and r.vars.data.question == question )|first %}
                                        <td>{{ form_widget(response) }}</td>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot class="full-width">
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th colspan="{{ questionnaire.contexts|length }}">
                                    <input class="ui green button my-4" type="submit" value="{{ 'validate.answers'|trans({},'buttons') }}">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Here is the "AuditOptionType" :

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\QuestionOption;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use AppBundle\Entity\QuestionResponse;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AuditOptionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $questionResponse = $event->getData();

            $question = $questionResponse->getQuestion();

            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->add('options', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'class' => QuestionOption::class,
                // 'placeholder' => '',
                'query_builder' => function (\AppBundle\Repository\QuestionOptionRepository $repository) use ($question) {
                    $options = $repository->getQuestionOptions($question->getId());
    
                    return $options;
                },
                'block_name' => 'html_options',
                'choice_attr' => function ($val, $key, $index) {
                    return array(
                        'option-object' => $val
                        );
                },
                'choice_label' => function (QuestionOption $option) {
                    return strip_tags($option->getDescription());
                },
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Choisir'
                ],
            ));
        });
    }
    
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => QuestionResponse::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_audit_option';
    }


}
```

Comment: So, you only need a single select? Or there is a collection of several selects?

Comment: There is a collection. I added the whole form so you can get an idea.

Comment: You need to modify the `AuditOptionType::class`, can you add the code here pls? You must have an EntityType or a ChoiceType, there you can get the result you want by changing the `required` and `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: @alexcm I just added it to the original post. I can make it required false but my placeholder doesn't show and the form can be submitted without choosing an option (which causes an error of course) so I don't want that.

Comment: I think using `'placeholder' => 'placeholder_message',
'required' => true,` will add the required atrtribute to your html selects and the placeholder will add an option without value selected by default. EDIT: you should comment this part `'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Choisir'],`

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much @alexcm !